# Is there anyway in firebug to select a section and find the relavent html and css?

Tags: html, css, firebug

I see in the HTML tab of firebug i can drill down into the html elements of the page and it will highlight those sections on the page.

Is there anyway to do the opposite where i simply highlight over some area on a page and it will point me to that html inside firebug so i can see the html and css that is generating this?

Comment: I haven't used Firefox for a while but I know that in Safari you can right-click the element and there's a menu option to inspect the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blue rectangle at the upperleft corner can be clicked. Then, hover over the page, and click at any element to show the HTML tree and relevant CSS properties.

This feature is useful if you don't know which element has to be inspected, but if you know the rough area of the elements. During the hover, a blue outline will appear around the hovered element.

[image: FireBug]

Answer (score 3):

You can right click in the page and choose `inspect element`. Chrome also features this. In IE 9 you can press `ctrl+b` with the developer tools window active. The next element you click will jump to the element in DOM explorer.

Answer (score 2):

There's a button with a mouse pointer over a blue rectangle. It allows you to go to the actual site and select something, which makes firebug highlight the relevant section of HTML and the styles related

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In firebug, click on the arrow with the box in the upper left. Then click on your item in the page.